# Setting the minimumValue (earliest date) in asp.net causes The MaximumValue cannot be less than the MinimumValue

Tags: asp.net

I am attempting to use the range validator to set a minimum date using minimumValue as I do not need a maximum value and the error comes up saying System.Web.HttpException: The MaximumValue  cannot be less than the MinimumValue 2002/09/15 of . Does anyone have any ideas on how I can remove this error?

```
Starting date 
<asp:TextBox  ID = "textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server"  MinimumValue ="2002/09/15" ControlToValidate = "textbox1"  ErrorMessage="after 14 September 2002"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asp:CompareValidator` instead of `asp:RangeValidator`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/db330ayw(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: can i add a date in the comparevalidator?

Comment: Yes, you can set a type - `Type="DataType" `. Check out the link I edited in. Cheers!

Comment: But how does it know what the minimum date is then because i need it to make any date before 2002/09/15 to be invalid

Comment: Set the ValueToCompare attribute as 2002/09/15 and set the Operator attribute to GreaterThanEqual, LesserThanEqual....

Answer (score 0):

Specify `type="date"` in your range validator